# Filter "exposed filter" data based on another "exposed filter"

Tags: views

I have to exposed filters from 2 vocabularies, filtering results for a page. I'm using views module for this
Is there a way to create a bridge between them ? For example when I select something from the first filter the data from the 2'nd filter will change based on what I selected on first filter, and backwards.

If i'm thinking well there is no way to create a direct connection between those 2 filters (vocabularies), we have to use what they have in common, the content. So i'm guessing I need to get vocaluray 1 terms from the content after filter 2 has selected something.

- Filter 2 -> generate content -> generate filter 1 data again

Is there a way to do this without "hardcoding" ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module for that

> This module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy.

Comment: I'm using 2 different vocabularies, from what I know this module is to display terms from a vocabulary not combining 2 or more vocabularies.

Comment: Try views_selective_filters module https://www.drupal.org/project/views_selective_filters